# How to invite people to a server using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a quick question, I can't seem to understand, is it possible to make a bot that will send invites to random people/people with some interest to a server? How would that be done using discord.py library?
Thank you!

Comment: To whom would you send it?

Comment: explain more pls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to send the links to random to people you can use random function after getting the peeople. But below is the code to send the server links to all the people in every server where the bot is in.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def link(ctx):
   count=0
   sent=[]
   server = ctx.message.guild
   try:
     link =await server.text_channels[0].create_invite( reason=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
   except:
     await ctx.send(f"i dont have permisssion to create link ")
     return
   for i in client.guilds:   
     for j in ctx.guild.members:
       ##If you want to send the links to random people you can use ``random.sample(ctx.guild.members,number_people)`` instead of ``(ctx.guild.members)`` in for loop. 
       ##Here number_people is the number of random invites to be sent in an server
       if not j.bot:
         if j.id not in sent:
           try:
             await j.send(link)
             sent.append(j.id)
             count=count+1
           except:
             continue
   await ctx.send(f"Invite has been successfully sent to {count} people in all the servers where the bot is in")
```

Answer (score -1):

to create invite using bot is below:

```py
@client.command()
async def send_invite(ctx,max_age=0,max_uses=0,temporary=False):
  invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age=max_age,max_uses=max_uses,temporary,temporary)
  await ctx.send(invite)
```